# show interface info in router with linux

Tags: linux, router, netgear-router

in Cisco routers there is such command as `show interfaces`. It outputs a lot of meta information for all the interfaces in the router (status: up/down, )

What are the similar commands I could run in my Netgear (6700) router? I was able to telnet.

`uname -a` returns "Linux R6700v3 2.6.36.4brcmarm+ .... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary tool I think you are looking for is

```
ifconfig
ifconfig -a
```

ifconfig displays the network interfaces, addressing information, and statistics. It does not come preinstalled by default all on Linux distributions, and there are a lot of alternatives that can provide networking information.

```
ip link show
ip a
netstat -i
arp -a
```

Example ifconfig output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.30.218.236  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.30.223.255
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe8a:770c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:5d:8a:77:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 139  bytes 31553 (31.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 12  bytes 936 (936.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: I believe [`ifconfig`, `arp` and `netstat` are deprecated in favor of `ip`](https://serverfault.com/a/503807).